# Is there a way to differentiate between uncles, aunts, grandparents?

Tags: vocabulario, género, parentesco

My wife told me that in Persian/Farsi, there are different words for "uncle", "aunt", "grandfather" and "grandmother" that indicate which side of the family they are from (father's brother, or mother's brother? etc.)

Is there anything like that in Spanish? I think not (there's just "tio", "tia", "abuelo" and "abuela"), but would be happy to be proven wrong.

### UPDATE

Apparently there is no common way to do this; how about:

**Abuelopa** (father's father)
**Abueloma** (mother's father)

**Abuelapa** (father's mother)
**Abuelama** (mother's mother)

**Tiopa** (father's brother)
**Tioma** (mother's brother)

**Tiapa** (father's sister)
**Tiama** (mother's sister)

Comment: It doesn't exist such a thing of abuelopa or abueloma, tiama or the whole part of your update. Not officially, at least. According to the country or the region, people call their grandparents different. Abuelito, papapapa, papapa or many things but it depends on the culture and the live we have for them. Look at the answer of luisluix. It's more complete.

Comment: I know they don't exist yet; I was proposing neologisms.

Comment: Those are some good propositions. Better start using them ;)

Comment: @Joze: I will, but will anybody understand me? It's like when I pronounce "evolution" the British way ("evil-oo-shen") - I get blank stares and people slowly back away, holding their hand in front of them defensively.

Answer (score 12):

You could say `tío paterno` or `tío materno`

Which is exactly what we do in English.. My paternal grandfather's name is James.

Comment: But now... how to distinguish my brother-in-law who married my sister from my brother-in-law who married my brother?  ;-)  *Cuñado filial* doesn't really work haha.

Comment: Assuming this is a heterosexual family tree, `cuñado` would be the husband of your sister and `cuñada` would be the wife of your brother.  Otherwise, you'll just have to distinguish it with more words as you did in your comment.

Comment: Right... That was the joke ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The common way would be:

> tío paterno `(father's brother)`, tío materno `(mother's brother)`
>
> tía paterna `(father's sister)`, tía materna `(mother's sister)`
>
> Abuelo paterno `(father's father)`, abuelo materno `(mother's father)`
>
> Abuela paterna `(father's mother)`, abuela materna `(mother's mother)`

If you want to be a bit more formal:

> tío por parte de mi padre `(father's brother)`, tío por parte de mi madre `(mother's brother)`
>
> tía por parte de mi padre `(father's sister)`, tía por parte de mi madre `(mother's sister)`
>
> Abuelo por parte de mi padre `(father's father)`, abuelo por parte de mi madre `(mother's father)`
>
> Abuela por parte de mi padre `(father's mother)`, abuela por parte de mi madre `(mother's mother)`

Comment: Just to complete your answer. In case of mother's sister you can say also tía materna or tía paterna in case of father's sister. So, you just need to play with paterno and paterna when it comes from father. Paterno for grandfather or uncle and paterna for grandmother and aunt. And materno or materna when it comes from mother. Materno for grandfather and uncle. Materna for grandmother and aunt. The formal way as luisluix is very common also.